# Error when using bool with assigned value to calculate transparency?

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a very odd error in Pine Script which I can't figure out.  If I try and set a `fill`'s transparency using a boolean variable combined with the ternary operator to calculate an integer, it works fine:

```
testBool = true
//testBool := false
cloudTransparency = testBool ? 75 : 100
fill(p1, p2, color = IsGreen ? color.green : color.red, transp=cloudTransparency)
```

But uncomment `testBool := false`, setting that variable to false, and I get this error:

> line 205: Cannot call 'fill' with arguments (plot, plot, color=series[color], transp=integer); available overloads: fill(hline, hline, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, const bool, string) => void; fill(plot, plot, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, input integer, const bool, string) => void

Why is this happening?  I have no idea why assigning a bool value to a variable would cause this to break.  What can I do to allow me to assign a value to that variable, and use its assigned value to calculate the transparency without an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `:=` converts variable `testBool`  to a series. And so all subsequent variables are also converted to a series.
You may be satisfied with a workaround

```
fill(p1, p2, color = testBool ? (IsGreen ? color.new(color.green, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75)) : (IsGreen ? color.new(color.green, 100) : color.new(color.red, 100)))
```

or you can calculate the color as a separate line

```
color_fill = testBool ? (IsGreen ? color.new(color.green, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75)) : (IsGreen ? color.new(color.green, 100) : color.new(color.red, 100))
fill(p1, p2, color = color_fill)
```

The result on the screen will meet your expectations.

Comment: Is there some way I can get a non-series integer based on a calculation?  The calculation only applies to this iteration of the code so I don't see why it has to be a series.

Comment: All variables that change at runtime become series. [Type system](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#const).

Comment: Pretty ridiculous restriction that `fill` can't accept series, then.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_fill) `transp` argument of the `fill` function doesn't accept `series int`, only `contant int` or `input int`

[image]

Comment: But why is my statement `cloudTransparency = testBool ? 75 : 100` generating a series?  It's just one int value.  And how can I generate the number that way, and pass it to the `transp` argument?